# AdMob: getting No fill from any mediaton ad network with test Banner

Tags: android, libgdx, admob, google-play-services

I'm developing an android game using Libgdx.
I'm trying to setup the Ad using AdMob included in the google-play-service-lib (8.1.0).

I can't understand the problem, this is how I set the Banner:

```
bannerGameScreenAdView = new AdView(this);
    bannerGameScreenAdView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.banner_bottom_in_game_screen));
    bannerGameScreenAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

    AdRequest bannerGameScreenAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("my_real_device_id")
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    bannerGameScreenAdView.loadAd(bannerGameScreenAdRequest);
```

The Unit Ad id is the one specified by the AdMob guide for obtaining test banners: *ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111*

This is the error I get:

```
12-10 21:23:19.265: I/Ads(3446): Starting ad request.
12-10 21:23:19.602: I/Ads(3446): Trying mediation network: 
12-10 21:23:19.603: I/Ads(3446): Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.DummyAdapter
12-10 21:23:19.604: W/Ads(3446): Could not instantiate mediation adapter: com.google.DummyAdapter. com.google.DummyAdapter
12-10 21:23:19.606: I/Ads(3446): No fill from any mediation ad networks.
```

Thank you as usual,

Luca

**UPDATE:**

If I change the AdSize of the AdView from SMART_BANNER to BANNER a banner is shown so, maybe, AdMob returns the error 3 (No fill from servers...) because for the current device (Nexus 5) there's no "smart banner" available.

**ALMOST SOLVED**

It seems to be that the problem was related to the AdSize I have chosen for the Banner. 
In particular the SMART_BANNER works on my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab)  but doesn't work for the lg Nexus 5.

Because I've noticed that test banners have been changed in style during these days , I believe that this could be due to some admob update of the service.

Comment: I've noticed that changing the AdSize of the AdView from AdSize. SMART_BANNER to AdSize.BANNER solves the problem. A standard banner is shown... now I'll try to understand the why, I'll post the answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Luca , did you solve it ??? I'm having this issue also.

Comment: Any solution for this, facing this issue from last 10 days.

Comment: Same problem! Smart banner worked fine for 1 year, now we are getting this problem on 200k devices!